# jquery hoverintent, works in chrome and firefox, hover when I hover over one element in internet explorer all hover functions are triggered

Tags: jquery, hover, explorer, hoverintent

I have created a vertical menu which expands out horizontally when hovered over. It works like a dream in chrome and firefox, however internet explorer doesnt like it for some reason. When hovering over any element they all pop out.

The function uses the jquery plugin hover intent which alters the css using animate.
Here is some of the code...

```
// one of these functions for each menu item, the inactive3 is obviously changed to the different list element

  $('li.inactive3').hoverIntent(expandit3, resetit3);

  function expandit3(){
$('li.inactive3').stop().animate({ width: "609px",height: "306px"}, "fast" );
  }

  function resetit3(){
$('li.inactive3').stop().animate({ width: "150px",height: "153px"}, "slow" );
  }


// the list elements are contained in the menudiv

#menudiv {
 z-index: 3;
 float: left;
 visibility: visible;
 position: fixed;
 display:block;

overflow:hidden;
}

// here is the list item css

  .inactive3 {
 z-index: 3;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 150px;
 height: 153px;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 visibility: visible;
clip:auto;
display:block;
}
```

Any ideas would be extemely helpful as I have been racking my brain about this problem for days, it just seems to be some kind of problem with iexplorer.

cheers

Comment: Formatted your code for you. Use the "Code" button or indent by 4 spaces to get nice listings.

Answer (score 0):

That should be the behavior in *all* browsers, to have per-element behavior, you should use `this` for the current element, like this:

```
$('li.inactive3').hoverIntent(expandit3, resetit3);
function expandit3(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ width: "609px",height: "306px"}, "fast" );
}
function resetit3(){
  $(this).stop().animate({ width: "150px",height: "153px"}, "slow" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now, just had to set the position of the list elements to relative, thanks for your help.